# Arranging 4 Indians, 4 Americans and 4 Russians in a row such that three consecutive people are of different nationalities

Tags: combinatorics

4  Indian,  4  American  and  4  Russian  delegates  have  to  be  seated  in  a  row  such  that  any  three  consecutive  people  in  a  row  are  of  three  different  nationalities.  In  how  many  ways  can  they  be  seated?

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  When you pose a question here, it is expected that you include your own thoughts on the problem.   Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Think of it this way: how many choices are there for the first person in the row? Then, how many choices for the second? the third? the fourth? and so on.

Comment: Once you have seated the first two persons, the nationalities of all the others are determined. This is because the next person to seat should be of the third nationality different from the previous two that were seated before. There are $3$ ways to choose the first person, and 2 ways to choose the second person. Therefore, there are $3\times 2=6$ ways to arrange the row.

Comment: @minghan: That's an answer.

Comment: @joriki Yes, and "3" is a number, and "dog" is an animal. It is useful to name and classify things. It structures knowledge. It helps understanding, as long as the category doesn't get confused for the thing in itself.

Comment: @minghan: Funny. What I meant was: Before I start writing a comment here, the prompt says "Avoid answering questions in comments." We have so many questions here on the site that are left unanswered, taking up space in the unanswered questions list, because they were answered in comments. That comment is a full answer; I don't see anything that's missing to turn it into a full answer. That will probably lead to the question remaining unanswered and wasting resources if you don't post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

12x8x4x3x3x3x2x2x2x1x1x1=3!(4!)^3 using fundamental counting principle.  Once the first two people are seated the order of the nationalities is determined.